# Node.js - Why isn't this code working?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have tried this code below to do things when there isn't anything found for that user when searching the database. This is using the twitch-irc library with the twitch-irc-db module for it (Node.js).

```
db.where('users', {name: user.username}).then(function(result) {
    if (!result) {
        console.log('No result lad');
    }
    var cid = result.items[0].cid;
    console.log(result.items[0].cid);
    if (!cid) {
        db.insert('users', {name: user.username, keys: 0}).then(function() {
            console.log(user.username + ' is new to the stream, generating them a blank database entry.');
        });
    }
});
```

For some reason, none of the console.log() lines above actually work. As you can see, I have tried the method of if (!result) AND if (!cid), neither of these work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible your query is failing for some reason and you are not tracking the error?

try to add `.fail`

```
db.where('users', {name: user.username}).then(function(result) {
    if (!result) {
        console.log('No result lad');
    }
    var cid = result.items[0].cid;
    console.log(result.items[0].cid);
    if (!cid) {
        db.insert('users', {name: user.username, keys: 0}).then(function() {
            console.log(user.username + ' is new to the stream, generating them a blank database entry.');
        });
    }
}).fail(function(err) {console.log(err)});
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I didn't actually know about using .fail to handle the errors, that will help soooo so much for all future developments. It turns out that the error being thrown was saying that it couldn't read cid from undefined, so then I turned towards result... I changed the first if statement to if (result == undefined) and that didn't do it, so then I moved further down the chain, changed it to if (result.items[0] == undefined), and that worked. I moved the db.insert and corresponding console.log into that first if statement and deleted the rest from within db.where. Thanks a lot buddy.